# How to import other component's config.ts file in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Following [this tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-a-reusable-modal-component-in-angular-9-using-ng-bootstrap-50c0aa5f3a65) I've created a reusable modal component. The modal itself is shown from other components (with an error `ERROR TypeError: ctx_r1.modalConfig is undefined`), but I couldn't personalize it, i.e. it is an empty box, behaving like a modal.

Modal component is structured as follow:

```
Modal component
   modal.component.html
   modal.component.ts
   modal.config.ts
```

where .config.ts looks like:

```
export interface ModalConfig {
    modalTitle: string;
...
}
```

Here is component B, where I want to open a personalized modal:

b.ts file:

```
import { Component, Injectable, Input, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
import { ModalConfig } from '@app/.../modal/modal.config';
import { ModalComponent } from '@app/.../modal/modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'b',
  templateUrl: './b.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ ModalComponent ]
})

export class BComponent {
    public modalConfig!: ModalConfig;
    @ViewChild('deleteConfirmModal') private modalComponent!: ModalComponent;

    async openModal() {
        this.modalConfig.modalTitle = "Confirm your action";
        return await this.modalComponent.open()
    }
}
```

b.html

```
<modal #deleteConfirmModal [modalConfig]="modalConfig">  </modal>
```

If I try to assign some value to modaConfig, then the empty modal is not shown anymore and I get a new similar error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.modalConfig is undefined
```

Does any one know what is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We can change the config to a class, so that it can be used as a `Type` as well as initializing the initial values, then you can add more properties if needed to!

Could you change the interface to a class

```
export class ModalConfig {
    modalTitle: string;
    
    constructor(modalTitle = '') {
       this.modalTitle  = modalTitle;
    }
}
```

Then you can change `b.com.ts` to

```
import { Component, Injectable, Input, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
import { ModalConfig } from '@app/.../modal/modal.config';
import { ModalComponent } from '@app/.../modal/modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'b',
  templateUrl: './b.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ ModalComponent ]
})

export class BComponent {
    public modalConfig!: ModalConfig = new ModalConfig(); // I've also tried @Input() public modalConfig!: ModalConfig;
    @ViewChild('deleteConfirmModal') private modalComponent!: ModalComponent;

    async openModal() {
        this.modalConfig.modalTitle = "Confirm your action"; // adding this, the error changes and the modal is not shown anymore
        return await this.modalComponent.open()
    }
}
```